# Wildfly deplyment error: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.DefaultDS"]

Tags: java, wildfly, datasource

I had next error while deployment ear on Wildfly 23:

```
Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.DefaultDS"]
```

I posted it to answer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed jboss-web.xml file containing defining third-side vendors datasource that i added previously and issue fixed.